# Mysql with in Query -Operand contains one column

Tags: mysql

I have this query, it is giving me error

Operand Should contains one column. But  i need two columns for now . Can anybody help me out

```
SELECT `business`.`id` AS business_id,
       `business`.`name` AS business_name,
       `business`.`address`,
       `business`.`address2`,
       `business`.`city`,
       `business`.`state`,
       `business`.`zipcode`,
       `business`.`lat`,
       `business`.`lon`,
       `service`.`id` AS ser_id,
       `service`.`name` AS service_name,
       (SELECT price, `price_verified`.`comments`
          FROM `price_verified`
               LEFT JOIN `price`
                  ON `price_verified`.`price_id` = `price`.`id`
         WHERE     `price`.`service_id` = ser_id
               AND `price_verified`.`status` = 1
        ORDER BY `price_verified`.`date_verified` DESC
         LIMIT 1)
  FROM service
       LEFT JOIN `business` ON `service`.`business_id` = `business`.`id`
 WHERE `service`.`business_id` = 1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS the error message says you can only have one result column in your sub-query.

either you have to concatenate the sub query result or have two sub queries for each column.

like:

```
(SELECT  concat(price,`price_verified`.`comments`)  as result
FROM `price_verified`  LEFT JOIN `price` ON `price_verified`.`price_id`=  `price`.`id` \n\
                WHERE `price`.`service_id`=ser_id  AND `price_verified`.`status`= 1  ORDER BY `price_verified`.`date_verified` DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: Then how i will separate comments and price

Comment: concat('price=', price, 'comment=', `price_verified`.`comments`) something like that?